# Store Value returned from Java Class in Class Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In my WSO2 ESB, I have a created Java class, which produces a string value as output. Now I am calling my Java class with "Class Mediator". How can I store the value retured from my Java class in my WSO2 ESB and show that as log in Log mediator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save values in property in class mediator as below,

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
  context.setProperty("testKey","Value in class mediator");
  return true;
}
```

and access the stored values as below,

```
<log>
  <property name="test log" expression="$ctx:testKey"/>
</log>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property in your java class for example `context.setProperty("propertyName","PropertyValue")`

Now as the property is set in your java class then you can use it anywhere in your sequence by using the expression `$ctx:propertyName` or try using `get-property(propertyName)` both would fetch the value but `$ctx` is performance is faster when compared to `get-property`